# How can I make my chicken and cow spawners more efficient?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft factions (server desteria) and I currently own 2 spawners, one chicken and one cow. I was wondering how I can make this more efficient. Right now I use a looting and fire aspect sword.

This came to me after seeing my chicken spawner spawning 2 at a time while my cow longer. I have the same light levels of 4 torches in each 5x7 room.

NOTE - This faction's server doesn't make special rules about spawners other than them having to be near you in order to spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly reduce the number of mobs around you. If there's too many mobs already spawned around you, then the spawner will work less well. If the number of mobs around you exceeds the maximum limit, the spawner will not work.

In terms of maximising your loot, it might be best to have you spawners constantly feeding into a mob grinder (I recommend viewing "chicken farm" and "cow farm" by [NimsTut on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/NimsGaming), he builds great compact ones) and then using the systems he suggests to kill them automatically (if you don't want to use your sword).